# Draggable Highcharts SVG Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

The demo here:
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/renderer

Is it possible to drag those labels around with the library? Or do we need jQuery UI?

Edit: I've tried to manipulate the SVG elements with jQuery UI draggable but it didn't not work

I'm interested to know, for those who have used this library, can I drag labels in this demo using the library?

Answer (score 1):

It is stated in the [download](http://www.highcharts.com/download) section that you can use the library with or without jQuery. Your answer was one click away...

Comment: But I've tried to manipulate the demo with jQuery draggable(), it did not work

Comment: Ok, but you did not state that initially, let that be a pointer to next time you ask a question. If you will use jQuery draggable, you will need jQuery as well. Depending on what you wish to do, there are several "draggable" plugins available in Highcharts.

http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/3/Draggable%20Points
http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/4/Draggable-Legend
http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/32/draggable-legend-box